# Manifold homotopic to product of two graphs

Tags: manifolds, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes, simplicial-complex

Consider two graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$, thought of as $1$-dimensional CW complexes. Suppose that $X = G_1\times G_2$ has the homotopy type of a manifold (with boundary). What can be said about the graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$?

I believe one of $G_k$ must be homotopic to the circle. If you consider a vertex with more than three edges, you can `pull' one of the edges along another and get a homotopic graph where that vertex has one less edge (and a new vertex with three edges). So we can reduce to the case of degree $3$ vertices. I want to argue that if neither $G_1$ nor $G_2$ is a circle, then the product will behave badly near the product of two degree $3$ vertices.

I am not entirely sure how to argue. I know that the cone on $A * B$ is the cone on $A$ times the cone on $B$, so there is a point in $X$ whose neighborhood is the cone on three points joined with three points (i.e., a cone on the [utilities problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_utilities_problem)). Since $X$ is homotopy equivalent to a manifold, there is a continuous map $X\to M$ (and a map back), so this `local structure' appears around some point in a manifold, but I do not see the way to a contradiction.

Does the fact that it is a $2$-complex tell us anything via Poincare duality somehow, like the dimension of the manifold is bounded (ignoring spheres and their quotients)? Or should I be `thinking globally' somehow? Alternative solutions are acceptable, though I'd prefer some comments on how to make the above sketchy thoughts better.

Comment: Every (finite) $2$-complex embeds in $\mathbb R^5$, and has a regular neighborhood which is a compact $5$-manifold with boundary that deformation retracts to that $2$-complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every finite CW complex is of the homotopy type of a compact manifold with boundary, by “fattening up the cells.” In particular, the product of two $S^1\vee S^1$s, viewed as graphs, is homotopy equivalent to the product of a solid two-holed torus with itself, which disproves your conjecture.

Comment: Ah, nice. Can you think of a 3-dimensional counterexample (trying to save my `cone on three utilities' intuition)?

Comment: @Ryan: If $G=S^1\vee S^1$ then $G\times G$ is not homotopy-equivalent to any 3-dimensional manifold (compact or not).

Comment: That is nice, but why?

Comment: @Ryan: See the first page of [this](http://www.numdam.org/article/SB_1975-1976__18__167_0.pdf) paper.